# c# FireBase generated string indexes deserialization

Tags: c#, json.net, firebase, deserialization

i have a clients list and i want to push them into firebase, i am using firesharp, but when i do, firebase creates a string index for every client i push.

the problem is when i want the data back i cant deserialize it because of the string indexes and the List class.

this is what i have:

```
 public class Client
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string mail { get; set; }
    public string adress { get; set; }
    public List kids { get; set; }


    public Cliente(string nameArg, string lastnameArg, int ageArg, string phoneArg, string mailArg, string adressArg)
    {
        name = nameArg;
        lastname = lastnameArg;
        age = ageArg;
        phone = phoneArg;
        mail = mailArg;
        adress = adressArg;
        kids = new List<kids>();
    }
}
```

then i made a class to hold this clients (not sure if this is a good idea any suggestion is welcome)

```
 public class ClientList
{
    public List<Client> clientList
    { get; set; }
}
```

so i push Client objects to the clientList in firebase like this:

```
public async void pushClient(Client c) {
        PushResponse response = await client.PushAsync("clientList", c);
        MessageBox.Show (response);//i use this line to check the index
    }
```

that response is always something like "Ahs74-djAdie8" <-- this is the index firebase gave to my Client object.

firebase json looks like this after the push:

```
{"clientList":{
    "Gfjy654-hfGfgv":{
        "name":"asasasas",
        "lastname":"ooooooo",
        "age":"22",
        "mail":"hhhh@hhh",
        "phone":"+665544581"
    },
    "H5j7su-UHudufu":{
        name:"asasasas",
        "lastname":"ooooooo",
        "age":"22",
        "mail":"hhhh@hhh",
        "phone":"+665544581"
    }
}
}
```

now when i try to get this data back and deserialize it doesnt work this is the method and the exception:

```
    private async void getClients()
    {
        FirebaseResponse response = await client.GetAsync("");
        list = response.ResultAs<ClientList>();
    }
```

> An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code

i tested changing manually the index in firebase to numbers and Instantly works, but am not tring to do that, i just want to deserialize it right!.

my clue is: List class doesnt work with string indexes; 
i am new in c#, have mercy on me :) Thx in advance;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to Updated Question**

You need to change `clientList` to be a dictionary rather than a list:

```
    public class ClientListResponse
    {
        public Dictionary<string, Client> clientList { get; set; }
    }
```

Having done so, in theory the JSON you show should now be successfully deserialized, with the dictionary keys being the `Gfjy654-hfGfgv` strings.

Comment: Hello, i made those mistakes because i wrote and translate the original json to make it easier to understand, but that is not even close to my real  problem that is the deserialization.

Comment: @Tymofek - did deserializing `clientList` as a `Dictionary<string, Client>` work?

Comment: Actually it was a List<Dictionary<string,int>>, anyway Firebase is not a good idea for a c# project right now. i changed my project.
Thx anyway you gave me the idea with your other answer.